# How to calculate boundary homomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-topology

[image]

Let $\partial_2:\Delta_2(X)\rightarrow\Delta_1(X)$ be a boundary homomorphism.

I get that $\partial_2(U)=(-1)^0V^{2}_{0}(U)+(-1)^1V^{2}_{1}(U)+(-1)^2V^{2}_{2}(U)=b-a+c$

Now $\partial_2(L)=(-1)^0V^{2}_{0}(L)+(-1)^1V^{2}_{1}(L)+(-1)^2V^{2}_{2}(L)=b-a+c$

But then $\partial_2(U)\neq-\partial_2(L)$. Is this normal?

Edit: perhaps I should change the vertices to $v_0$, $v_1$, and $v_2$, where the clockwise ordering of the vertices starting from bottom left is $v_0, v_2, v_1,v_2$.

Comment: The projective plane isn't orientable; I suspect you are applying shortcuts that are based on that assumption that everything in a drawing is aligned with some orientation, but that's not true in this diagram. (Nor can you make it true by changing the orientations of things)

Comment: So if the space is orientable (e.g. a torus), then $\partial_2(U)=-\partial_2(L)$? How do you define orientable?

Answer (score 0):

You have gotten the orientation of the 2-simplex $L$ incorrect.  It is not about the clockwise ordering.

What you do is follow the longest path around the simplex in the direction of the arrows; this defines the orientation and the starting point.  The path is $v$ through $c$ to $v$ through $a$ to $w$.  Then the boundary homomorphism is: cover up the vertices one at a time in order, find the remaining edge, then do the alternating sum of all these.  This gives $\partial_2 L=a-b+c$.  So, not only is it fine for $\partial_2 U\neq -\partial_2 L$, but they don't need to have much to do with each other!

The figure on page 105 of Hatcher is somewhat misleading.  Take a look at the diagram at the top of page 103 very carefully, then use it to read the formula for the boundary homomorphism on page 105.